# Adding slicing numbers using a loop

Tags: python, loops, slice

I want to know how can I add these numbers in Python by using a loop? Thanks

```
num=input("Enter your number: ")

ansAdd= int(str(num)[7])+int(str(num)[5])+int(str(num)[3])+int(str(num)[1])

print....
```

Answer (score 1):

you want to do it using a loop, here you go:

```
ansAdd = 0
for x in [7,5,3,1]:
  ansAdd += int(str(num)[x])
```

However, using list comprehension is more pythonic

Comment: `for x in [7,5,3,1]: print 1.7 * int(str(num)[x])`.  I would advise you find a good Python tutorial and work through it.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> s = '01234567'
>>> sum(map(int, s[1::2]))
16
```

Here is how it works:

`s[1::2]` takes a slice of the string starting at index `1` to the end of the string stepping by `2`.  For more information on slices see the [Strings](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) section of the Python Tutorial.

[`map`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map) takes a function and an [iterable](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-iterable) (strings are iterable) and applies the function to each item, returning a list of the results.  Here we use `map` to convert each string-digit to an `int`.

[`sum`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sum) takes an iterable and sums it.

If you want to do this without the `sum` and `map` builtins, without slices, and with an explicit for-loop:

```
>>> s = '01234567'
>>> total = 0
>>> for i in range(1, len(s), 2):
...     total += int(s[i])
...
>>> total
16
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> num=input()
12345678
>>> sum(map(int,num[:8][1::2]))
20
```

here `num[:8][1::2]` returns only the numbers required for `sum()`, `num[:8]` makes sure only the elemnets up to index `7` are used in calculation and `[1::2]` returns `1,3,5,7`

```
>>> num[:8][1::2]
>>> '2468'
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to sum odd-numbered digits from user input. To do it with a loop:

```
num_str = raw_input("Enter your number: ")
ansAdd = 0
for digit in num_str[1::2]:
    ansAdd += int(digit)
```

(The syntax `[1::2]` is python's [string slicing](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) -- three numbers separated by `:` that indicates start index, stop index and step. An omitted value tells python to grab as much as it can.)

There's a better way to do this without using a traditional loop:

```
num_str = raw_input("Enter your number: ")
ansAdd = sum(int(digit) for digit in num_str[1::2])
```

In python 2, `input` executes the entered text as python code and returns the result, which is why you had to turn the integer back into a string using `str`.

It is considered a security risk to use `input` in python 2, since the user of your script can enter any valid python code, and it will be executed, no questions asked. In python 3 `raw_input` has been renamed to `input`, and the old `input` was removed (use `eval(input())` instead).